# How to fix: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I've been through a bunch of existing posts but couldn't get this to
work. I'm trying to build a query get all the records in a table and
an extra column. The extra column is populated by this logic - the
first value represented in the row which has same session ID as the
original record and has ToolName=ReportingTool. When I try to
implement the query like this, I get this error.

I tried doing a left join but the problem there is I don't know how to
limit the left join output (from the right table's select) to 1. This
causes multiple joins on the left and the no. of records returned
changes. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
      *
      FROM [TraceDB].[dbo].[TelemetryLogs] AS TelemetryOuter

  LEFT JOIN [TraceDB].[dbo].[TelemetryLogs] AS TelemetryInner
  ON 
    TelemetryInner.SessionID = TelemetryOuter.SessionID AND 
    TelemetryInner.ToolName='ReportingTool' AND 
    TelemetryInner.Name='Identity' AND
    TelemetryInner.SessionID = ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM [TraceDB].[dbo].[TelemetryLogs] AS TelemtryIntInt
        WHERE TelemtryIntInt.SessionID=TelemetryInner.SessionID
        )

  WHERE 
    TelemetryOuter.ToolName ='ReportingTool'
```

EDIT: Fixed a comma which got introduced as a copy paste type

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 *,` - that comma shouldn't be there.

Comment: Comma was a copy paste typo

Comment: "I tried doing a left join but the problem there is I don't know how to limit the left join output (from the right table's select) to 1." - `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 1 TelemtryIntInt.SessionID
```

In your inner SELECT.  You're currently returning the whole row and you can't compare a scalar sessionID against a whole row.